# Function List Exercise: List within list not printing

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, for-loop

I have been asked to create 3 functions to create Vet Records. I have to use 2 functions to validate the Integer input and String Input respectively. I have completed majority of the code but the final part doesn't get printed when I run the code. My code is as follows:

```
def getNewVetRecord():  
    getNewVetRecord=[]    
    return getNewvetRecord

def getValidInteger():   
    Ask_for_value = True  
    while(Ask_for_value == True):
        try:
            ID = int(input("Pet ID: "))
            Ask_for_value = False
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid integer")

    return ID

def getValidString(): 
    Ask_for_value = False
    Input_String = ("")
    while(Ask_for_value == False):
        Input_String = input("Pet Name: ")
        Ask_for_value = Input_String.isalpha()
        if(Ask_for_value == False):
            print("Please enter a valid name")          
    return Input_String

def func():
    stringValue = getValidString();
    integerValue = getValidInteger();
    species = input("species:")
    ownername = input("owner first name:")
    owner_last_name = input("owner last name:")
    x=[]
    x.append(stringValue)
    x.append(integerValue)
    x.append(species)
    x.append(ownername)
    x.append(owner_last_name)
    return x

def main():
    x=[]      
    x.append(func())
    x.append(func())
    x.append(func())
    print( 'ID  Pet Name   Species\tOwner Name' )
    print( '--  --------   -------\t----------' )
    getVetRecord=[]

    for x in getVetRecord:
        for ind in x:
            print(format(getVetRecord[1][ind], "3d"), format(getVetRecord[2][ind]+"", "11s"), format("", "1s"),\
                  format(getVetRecord[3][ind]+"", "10s"),  format("", "2s"), getVetRecord[5][ind],',', getVetRecord[4][ind])


main()
```

It is doing the important part correctly, (validation and input) but it is not printing the answer.

[It shows the following when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sto9g.png)

Comment: In main(), you set getVetRecord=[] which is empty.  How is the for loop supposed to find anything to print?

Comment: @mkstlwtz Could you please suggest me the right way to print it? I realize that there is something wrong the main function but I am not being able to correct it.